# Windows Phone Push Notification By Azure Notification Hub

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone-8, notifications, push-notification

I am android app developer .Now, I am developing app for windows phone . I am integrating push notification in windows phone first time by Azure notification Hub. I want help for notification Hub. How to integrate? How to send notification to selected device not to all?

I was integrated notification but after some time notification is stop. I have done with many notification hub credentials. Now notification is coming.

```
    private async void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
    {
        StorageFile MyDBFile = null;
        try
        {
            // Read the db file from DB path
            MyDBFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(DB_PATH);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            if (MyDBFile == null)
            {
                // Copy file from installation folder to local folder.
                IsolatedStorageFile iso = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
                // Create a stream for the file in the installation folder.
                using (Stream input = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(DbConst.DATABASE, UriKind.Relative)).Stream)
                {
                    // Create a stream for the new file in the local folder.
                    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream output = iso.CreateFile(DB_PATH))
                    {
                        // Initialize the buffer.
                        byte[] readBuffer = new byte[4096];
                        int bytesRead = -1;

                        // Copy the file from the installation folder to the local folder. 
                        while ((bytesRead = input.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length)) > 0)
                        {
                            output.Write(readBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        var channel = HttpNotificationChannel.Find("MyPushChannel");
        if (channel == null)
        {
            channel = new HttpNotificationChannel("MyPushChannel");
            channel.Open();
            channel.BindToShellToast();
        }

        channel.ChannelUriUpdated += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelUriEventArgs>(async (o, args) =>
        {
            //var hub = new NotificationHub("<hub name>", "<connection string>");
            var hub = new NotificationHub("mnokhgjhjhjbohkjkl", "Endpoint=sb://connect-hub.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=DefaultListenSharedAccessSignature;SharedAccessKey=RM6jjnbjnbjAnjhttD4yxqnknknklmkmnkkmkkkmmkbnl5rSk=");
            Registration x= await hub.RegisterNativeAsync(args.ChannelUri.ToString());
            //mChennelURI = x.ChannelUri;
            Debug.WriteLine("Chennel URI: " + x.ChannelUri);

            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            { 
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(args.ChannelUri.ToString());

            });


        });
        channel.ErrorOccurred += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelErrorEventArgs>(async (o,args) =>
        {
            // Error handling logic for your particular application would be here.
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                // Show the notification since toasts aren't 
                // displayed when the app is currently running.
                MessageBox.Show(String.Format("A push notification {0} error occurred.  {1} ({2}) {3}", args.ErrorType, args.Message, args.ErrorCode,args.ErrorAdditionalData));


            });
        });

        // Handle the event that is raised when a toast is received.
        channel.ShellToastNotificationReceived +=new EventHandler<NotificationEventArgs>((o, args) =>
            {
                string message = "";
                foreach (string key in args.Collection.Keys)
                {
                    message += args.Collection[key] + ": ";
                }

                //string[] separators = { "#"};
               // string[] words = message.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
               // string type = words[0];
               // string title = words[1];
               // string body = words[2];
               // string attach = words[3];
               //string date = words[4];
                //string time = words[5];
                //string msdId = words[6];
                //string groupIDS = words[7];

                //foreach (var word in words)
                    //Console.WriteLine(word);
                Console.WriteLine("Push notification : " + message);
                Debug.WriteLine("Push notification : " + message);
                Debugger.Log(1, "Push", "Push notification : " + message);
                Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                {
                    // Show the notification since toasts aren't 
                    // displayed when the app is currently running.
                    MessageBox.Show(message);
                    //<Temp>
                   // DatabaseHelperClass dbHelper = new DatabaseHelperClass();
                   // dbHelper.Insert(new Msg(msdId, groupIDS, type, title, body, attach, date, time, Constants.NO));
                    //</Temp>

                });

            });

    }
```

Comment: I have integrated push notification push was coming but after some day. Now no push. I have tried to create many notification hub but non of these is success. I hope device is not registering

Comment: azure notificationhub is having registration expiry of 90 days. if you are not updating your registration in 90 days. then after expiry hub will stop sending notification to expired devices.